# Can I use someone's group name when I write Java library?

Tags: java, spring

I want to write spring framework extension. named xxxx.
Can I use `org.springframework` group name? Is it good choice?
Is it conventionally occupied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend NOT using it.  The system is designed to prevent clashes in namespaces.  What if Spring created something with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the reverse of a domain name that you own, eg if you own `example.org`, then you put it under `org.example`, etc.

Don't squat in other people's namespaces without their permission.